# dnxcore50 framework support in ASP.Net 5 Class Library Package project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

I am trying to develop my first ASP.Net web application and in my solution I have two projects. A `Web Application` and `Class Library (Package)` and noticed that the Web App has this for it's framework inside the `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

My understanding is that code makes my Web App target Net 5.0 Core but if I look at the `project.json` for the Class Library I see this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
            "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
            "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
        }
    }
}
```

I have never heard of `dotnet5.4` and what I read from google just confuses me. I think the `net451` is the equivalent to `dnx451` but I am not 100% on that.

What do I need to change in my `project.json` to get it to target the new .Net 5.0 core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of the upcoming [.NET Standard Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md).  You can see the changes regarding this specific to rc1 [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98), the main part being;

> Only class libraries should change to target net4x and dotnet5.x. For
>   class libraries the recommended conversion steps are:
>
> In project.json:
>
> - Change dnx4x to net4x (e.g. `dnx451` to `net451`)
> - Change `dnxcore50` to
>     `dotnet5.4`
>
> And in your CS files:
>
> - Change `#if DNX451` to `#if NET451`
> - Change `#if DNXCORE50` to `#if DOTNET5_4`

Comment: Thanks. That bring up another problem/question I have about Entity Framework 7. Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370874/entityframework-commands-in-asp-net-5-class-library-package and if you know the answer give me another hand?