# EntityFramework Commands in ASP.Net 5 Class Library Package?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to develop my first ASP.Net web application and in my solution I have two projects. A `Web Application` and `Class Library (Package)`. When I build the ASP.Net 4.5 version of this application I put my `Entity Framework 6` entities into a class library, so I am doing that in the `ASP.Net 5` version. The problem is when I install `EntityFramework.Commands` to the class library I get the error:

> The dependency EntityFramework.Command 7.0.0-rc1-final in Project DBEntities does not support framework .NetPlatform, Version = 5.4

My understanding from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366900/dnxcore50-framework-support-in-asp-net-5-class-library-package-project) is that `dotnet5.4` is the new .Net 5 which is supposed to be supported by EF7.

Here is my `project.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "FFInfo.DAL Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Mathew" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet5.4": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
}
```

Did I install the wrong package, is EF7 changed so much that I am building out the class wrong, or am I missing something in my json file?

EDIT:
New project.json file based off suggestions

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "FFInfo.DAL Class Library",
    "authors": [ "Mathew" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet5.4": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-*",
                "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-*",
                "Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources": {
                    "version": "1.0.0-*",
                    "type": "build"
                },
                "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*",
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-*"
            }
        },
        "netcore50": {
            "bin": {
                "assembly": "lib\\netcore50\\_._"
            }
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
            "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The framework `dotnet5.4` is synonym of `dnxcore50` and not `dnx451` (see [the official announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98)). I personally find the changes of names vary bad. **I would recommend you to rename `dotnet5.4` to `dnxcore50` first of all.** Probably you should use `net451` or `dnx451` instead of `"frameworks"."dotnet5.4"."dependencies"` if your class library is for ASP.Net 4.5 mostly? In any way I would recommend you to add `"dnx451": { }` (or `"net451": { }`) back to `"frameworks"`. If you would be able to reproduce the problem I can try to help more.

Comment: @Oleg I don't want it to target `.Net 4.5` I want it to target `.Net 5.0 core` This `Class Library` is for the `ASP.Net 5` version of my web app.

Comment: I think that your problem could be solved by **renaming `"dotnet5.4"` to `"dnxcore50"`**. If it would work I would post my answer with more detailed explanation. I think that you can remove additionally all `"dependencies"` included in `"frameworks"."dotnet5.4"` (`"frameworks"."dnxcore50"`) and probably use the common `"dependencies"`, but include only really required dependencies. The optimization of `"frameworks"``is independent from your main problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of your problem have pure technical nature. [The announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98) declares renaming of dnx451 to net451 and dnxcore50 to dotnet5.4, but one recommend to use such renaming **only for class libraries** (which you publich on NuGet for example to share with other). If I understand you correctly, that you develop *application* which uses class libraries and thus you should use `dnxcore50` instead of `dotnet5.4`. Thus **you need just rename the string "dotnet5.4" to the string `"dnxcore50" in the file`project.json` to fix the problem**.

Independent from the above recommendation I want to add my understanding of your problem, *why* you get the error about EntityFramework.Command 7.0.0-rc1-final.

I understand the renaming of frameworks as the step in direction to future changes which plan Microsoft. On the other side all names of frameworks will be interpreted just as different names. I suggest you to compare the information about the dependencies displayed on the page https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/7.0.0-rc1-final from the corresponding information from https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer/7.0.0-rc1-final. The dependencies of `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` (which have no problems with the usage of `dotnet5.4`) looks like on the picture

[image]

I marked read the part responsible for `dotnet5.4`. On the other side the dependencies of `EntityFramework.Commands` looks like on the picture below:

[image]

where there are no ".NETPlatform 5.4" section which corresponds the new name `dotnet5.4`.

I suppose that it's **a bug in [the part](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands/project.json#L61-L64) of `project.json` of `EntityFramework.Commands`**:

```json
"netcore50": {
  "bin": {
    "assembly": "lib\\netcore50\\_._"
  }
}
```

I suppose that one have to change `netcore50` to `dotnet5.4` in the lines to support new framework name `dotnet5.4` correctly. One chould replace the content of `"netcore50"` to the copy from `dnxcore50` (see [the lines](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands/project.json#L49-L59)):

```json
"dotnet5.4": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.Console": "4.0.0-*",
    "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-*"
  }
}
```

Probably one should event increase some version numbers of the dlls referenced above, but you still will be not able to use `EntityFramework.Commands` under `"dotnet5.4"` till the new fixed version will be published.

**UPDATED:** I posed [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4143) to the EntityFramework developer team. I'll include the response from Microsoft on the issue after I'll get it.

Comment: But `EntityFramework.Commands` is not a Class Library, its an [application](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands/Commands/Program.cs)...

Comment: @StaffordWilliams: I think that there are some differences in terminology currently. For me DLL is not Application. Independent from the classification of "EntityFramework.Commands" it have to be compiled with `"dotnet5.4"` as `"frameworks"` in [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands/project.json#L19) if one want to allow to use it in applications, which use it and be compiled for `dotnet5.4` too. You can try to reproduce the problem in some project which use EntityFramework. You will get the error by renames `dnxcore50` to `dotnet5.4`.

Comment: I tried to copy the lies you linked to but now I get `The dependecny Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved`. and the same error for `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime` so I don't think just replacing is the solution

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: *Where* you tried to copy the lines (in the source of `EntityFramework.Commands` or in your project)? What I mean that the developers of `EntityFramework.Commands` have to create new version which support `dotnet5.4`, but you have no chance to do this. The way which I recommended to you: **renaming `"dotnet5.4"` to `"dnxcore50"` in your `project.json`**.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Youe last `project.json` contains many errors: 1) you should remove `"netcore50"` part; 2) you should rename `"dotnet5.4"` to `"dnxcore50"`; 3) you should move `"dependencies": {  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",  "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final" }` on the correct place **out of** `"frameworks"`, like you had originally. The `"dependencies"` describes **common** dependency of your project which are independent from the framework.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry, I don't under stand all your suggested changes. Can you amend your answer with an example `project.json`. I got the remove `netcore50` and the rename but not sure where you want me to move the other stuff to.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Just get the `project.json`, which you originally posted, and rename the string `"dotnet5.4"` to `"netcore50"`. Nothing more. I formulated the suggestion in the first paragraph of my answer. All other long text of my answer, which I included in my answer, just described the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry was reading to much into your answer. I reverted back to my original `project.json` file and did the rename. The errors are now gone and the project builds. Thank you

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: You are welcome! I know my problem with writing too long and too detailed answers. :-) I will inform you about the progress of [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4143) which I posted.