# EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-rc1-final does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class library I am trying to build with EF 7 aka EF core.

I understand that in order to run migrations etc, I need to add the EF commands package, after I do so, I get this error:

The dependency EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-rc1-final does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4

Any idea on how to solve this?

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Class Library",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }

}
```

Comment: Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34371436/315935). I suppose it should answer your question. By the way [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4143), which I mention at the end of the answer is closed now and the bug is fixed in RC2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityFramework Commands in ASP.Net 5 Class Library Package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370874/entityframework-commands-in-asp-net-5-class-library-package)